# Testing SQL connections with UDL file

Tags: windows-server, connectivity, sql-server-2000, testing

I am testing SQL connectivity between a SQL server (windows server 2000) and client PC that has no SQL tools installed (windows 2000 SP4). The client PC runs a java application that needs to connect to the DB. from what I can tell port 1433 comes up ESTABLISHED and enters a TIME_WAIT state. working with the networking team we are trying to determine connectivity issues outside of the java application.

I discovered the UDL test file process (never heard of this before and not a SQL guy) and am wondering a few things. According to the stuff I have googled I should run the test using "SQL Server Native Client" but in my providers options that is not a choice. Will the test not be accurate if I were to use OLE DB Provider for SQL Server?

[image]